# Displaying data retrieved from Parse in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

After all progress i made with your answers, my issue changed. So i am changing my question with clearer way. I have an UITableView which is showing my retrieved data from Parse.com. So i made a NSMutableArray for adding objects to that array when they are retrieved. But my problem is even i add objects to NSMutableArray, my table does not show anything but default screen of UITableView. I thing the issue is UITableView is formed before my NSMutableArray got its objects. Here is my code:

Note: The PropertyClass is the class which has the properties of my objects.

At MyTableViewController.h

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController  <CLLocationManagerDelegate>  { 
    PFObject *object;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *MyTableView;
@end
```

At UITableViewController.m

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()
@property(strong)NSMutableArray *myNSMutableArray;
@end


@implementation MyTableViewController
@synthesize myNSMutableArray,MyTableView;

-(void) retrievingDataFromParse{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyObjectsClass"];
    [query whereKey:@"ObjectsNumber" lessThanOrEqualTo:10];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);

            if (objects.count==0) {
                NSString *objectError = @"There no object retrieved from Parse";
                PropertiesClass *PC = [[PropertiesClass alloc]initWithPropert1:objectError Propert2:nil Propert3:nil Propert4:nil];
                [myNSMutableArray addObject:PC];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {

                object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString *Propert1 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert1"];
                NSNumber *Propert2 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert2"];
                NSNumber *Propert3 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert3"];
                NSString *Propert4 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert4"];

              PropertiesClass *PC = [[PropertiesClass alloc]initWithPropert1:Propert1 Propert2:Propert2 Propert3:Propert3 Propert4:Propert4];
             [myNSMutableArray addObject:PC];

            };


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }


    }];




}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myNSMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self retrievingDataFromParse];
    [MyTableView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [myNSMutableArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PropertiesClass *PC= [myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=PC.Propert1;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What and why doesn't work?

Comment: Please check the edited question to find the my approach.

Comment: I inserted an edit for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code i see that you never create a UITableViewCell, you should change this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PropertyClass *PC = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = PC.x;
    return cell;
}
```

with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (nil == cell){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    PropertyClass *PC = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = PC.x;
    return cell;
}
```

the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` return a UITableViewCell only if there are unused, but already allocated, cells in your table view. otherwise it returns nil.

Also when you update the mutable array containing all your data you should call `[yourTableView reloadData]` to force the table view to reload its content.

Comment: i implemented your suggestions. At  `if (nil == cell){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }` an error appears about autorelease is not available at ARC. At [yourTableView reloadData], i cant find any message as reloadData

Comment: "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: return a UITableViewCell only if there are unused, but already allocated, cells in your table view. otherwise it returns nil" is not true when using storyboard prototypes.

Comment: @user2393702 you should only remove the autorelease to let the error disappear

Comment: @TimothyMoose you are right, i have never used the storyboard prototypes yet. looking at the doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html the problem could be that he has not registered a nib or a class before calling this method.

Comment: @user2393702 I would first suggest setting a breakpoint on the line `cell.textLabel.text = PC.x` and inspect the local variables to determine whether cell and/or PC.x are nil (unless I've missed something where you've already determined this) so we can narrow down the problem
.

Comment: have you ever initialized it?

Comment: you have to initialize the var: `self.myNsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array]`, you can do this in the ¡init` or in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller.

Comment: last paragraph of my response: _Also when you update the mutable array containing all your data you should call [yourTableView reloadData] to force the table view to reload its content._

Comment: try to put some NSLog in your code and see where you get empty objects, check how many times `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`is called and stuff like that. Also your code in the question is a little messed up, try to clean it a little bit and put all the code of the object that implement the UITableViewDataSource if you can

Comment: Does `[yourTableView reloadData]` relaod `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)`section method too? Because i have a thought about that cell number is loading before adding objects to `myNSMutableArray`. When i start simulating i am seeing all cells while my NSMutableArray having 2 objects.

Comment: Somehow i correct my code an it is working know. Thank you for providing me help to make a progress.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite cryptic. Few suggestions here.

First, rename variables and methods with **camelCaseNotation** (camel case notation). For example, `MyMutableArray` should be `myMutableArray`. `RetrievingDataFromParse`  should be `retrievingDataFromParse` (and so on). Start upper case letter are for classes.

Second, what does this code mean (I put comment on your code)?

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {
    // where do you have defined object?
    object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *x = [object objectForKey:@"x"];
    NSNumber *y = [object objectForKey:@"y"];
    NSNumber *z = [object objectForKey:@"z"];
    NSString *t = [object objectForKey:@"t"];

    // is Mekan a subclass of PropertiyClass or what else?
    PropertiyClass *Properties = [[Mekan alloc]initWithx:x y:y z:z t:t]  
    // what's MekanKalibi? Maybe you need to add Properties
    [MyMutableArray addObject:MekanKalibi];
}
```

**Edit**

If you don't use iOS6 `- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` you should `alloc-init` cells.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell) {
    // alloc-init a new cell here...
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // or if you don't use ARC
    // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

PropertyClass *PC = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = PC.x;
return cell;
```

**Edit 2**

I don't know how parse works but I suppose it manages async requests. So, at the end of your for loop, just call reload data in the table.

Comment: thank you for your warning and sorry for those errors. i simply copy and paste my code from xcode and change variable,classes with a more understandable way for English. So those errors come from that.

Comment: Could you share other details? Please also maintain a good format.

Comment: i shared some details, i am using iOS6 and ARC. I think the problem is in setting or getting NSMutableArray because when implement that code {Nslog(@"%@",PC.x)} i get null at NSlog

Comment: Somehow i correct my code an it is working know. Thank you for your answers and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Parse states:
The InBackground methods are asynchronous, so any code after this will run immediately.  Any code that depends on the query result should be moved inside the completion block above.

I had the same problem. When you reload the table, you need to move it so it is inside the block. Worked for me.

I'm not 100% sure how the asynchronous parts affect it so. I know that the start of my viewDidload and the end occured then this block, hence the problem.

People should probably up this as this solves the issue.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is reload tableView in the block... this will show data.

for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {

```
            object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *Propert1 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert1"];
            NSNumber *Propert2 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert2"];
            NSNumber *Propert3 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert3"];
            NSString *Propert4 = [object objectForKey:@"Propert4"];

          PropertiesClass *PC = [[PropertiesClass alloc]initWithPropert1:Propert1 Propert2:Propert2 Propert3:Propert3 Propert4:Propert4];
         [myNSMutableArray addObject:PC];

        };


    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

**[MyTableView reloadData];**

}];
```